# make logic component reusable in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i have a few very similar components with the same logic

```
import { useDetectClick } from 'src/utils/useDetectClick';
import ColumnMenu from 'src/components/presentational/menus/ColumnMenu';

const ColumnMenuContainer = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectClick(false);
  const onClick = (): void => {
   setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

 return (
  <>
   <ColumnMenu onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive} />
  </>
 );
};

export default ColumnMenuContainer;
```

and example of another one:

```
import { useDetectClick } from 'src/utils/useDetectClick';
import TaskMenu from 'src/components/presentational/menus/TaskMenu';

const TaskMenuContainer = () => {
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectClick(false);
 const onClick = (): void => {
  setIsActive(!isActive);
};

 return (
  <>
   <TaskMenu onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive} />
  </>
 );
};

export default TaskMenuContainer;
```

The only difference is Component name which they are returning. It look's like i'm repeating myself. I am wondering how to make it Reusable (if only it's possible). I thought about passing component (taskMenu etc.) to one universal Menu component as a prop, but i can't find any similar issue anywhere in web and don't know how to do it.

EDIT:

```
import { useDetectClick } from 'src/utils/useDetectClick';

interface Props{
  Component:React.ReactNode;
}

const ClickableContainer : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({Component}) => {
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectClick(false);
 const onClick = (): void => {
   setIsActive(!isActive);
 };

 return <Component onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive} />;
};

export default ClickableContainer;
```

When i am trying this solution, this error occurs:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

And it's underlining "Component".

EDIT - WORKING SOLUTION:

```
import { useDetectClick } from 'src/utils/useDetectClick';

interface NestedComponentProps {
  onClick: () => void;
  isActive: boolean;
}

interface Props {
  Component: React.FC<NestedComponentProps>;
}

const Menu: React.FC<Props> = ({ Component }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectClick(false);
  const onClick = (): void => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  return <Component onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive} />;
};

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the component to use as a prop. The important (and somewhat silly) detail to remember here is that *the variable name needs to be upper-case*!

```js
import { useDetectClick } from 'src/utils/useDetectClick';

const ClickableContainer = ({Component}) => {
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectClick(false);
 const onClick = (): void => {
   setIsActive(!isActive);
 };

 return <Component onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive} />;
};

export default ClickableContainer;
```

You can then reuse that:

```js
import TaskMenu from 'src/components/presentational/menus/TaskMenu';
import ColumnMenu from 'src/components/presentational/menus/ColumnMenu';
import ClickableContainer from './ClickableContainer';

const TaskMenuContainer = () => <ClickableContainer Component={TaskMenu} />;
const ColumnMenuContainer = () => <ClickableContainer Component={ColumnMenu} />;
```

Comment: Seems that this solution doesn't work with typescript, please see my edited question.

Comment: I finally figured out working solution with typescript, it's in my question.